# Can I skip ahead with a quadratic congruential generator?

Tags: cryptanalysis, pseudo-random-generator

I have a congruential generator where
$$
r_{n+1} = r_n^2 - c\;(mod\;p)
$$
known $r_0$, $c$ and $p$ can i get $r_n$ without having to compute all the previous values?

Comment: Yes but leaning on the word **all** in your question. You can do what has been termed fast skipping to avoid having to calculate **all** previous values.